# Create a typing.Annotated instance with variadic args in older Python

Tags: python, type-hinting

The question is simply how to reproduce this:

```
import typing

a = [1, 2, 3]
cls = typing.Annotated[int, *a]
```

or even this:

```
import typing

cls1 = typing.Annotated[int, 1, 2, 3]
unann_cls = typing.get_args(cls1)[0]
metadata = cls1.__metadata__
cls2 = typing.Annotated[unann_cls, *metadata]
```

in Python 3.9-3.10. `Annotated[int, *a]` is a syntax error in <3.11 so `typing_extensions.Annotated` shouldn't help here. "Nested Annotated types are flattened" suggests the following code:

```
cls2 = unann_cls
for m in metadata:
    cls2 = typing.Annotated[cls2, m]
```

and it seems to work but surely there should be a more clean way?

Comment: Self-comment: while `__metadata__` is documented only in 3.11+ it exists in 3.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the expression

```
obj[1, 2, 3]
```

`1, 2, 3` is just a tuple literal. It's exactly the same as

```
x = 1, 2, 3
obj[x]
```

We're simply passing the tuple  `(1, 2, 3)` to [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).

To get the behavior you want, you can wrap the tuple literal with parentheses so that the syntax for sequence unpacking inside a tuple literal kicks in:

```
>>> typing.Annotated[(int, *a)]
typing.Annotated[int, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Oh, that's pleasantly simple.